# Most efficient way to convert Python multidimensional list to CSV file?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, export-to-csv

I want to output a multidimensional list to a CSV file.

Currently, I am creating a new DataFrame object and converting that to CSV. I am aware of the csv module, but I can't seem to figure out how to do that without manual input. The populate method allows the user to choose how many rows and columns they want. Basically, the data variable will usually be of form [[x1, y1, z1], [x2, y2, z2], ...]. Any help is appreciated.

```
FROM populator IMPORT populate
FROM pandas IMPORT DataFrame

data = populate()
df = DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('output.csv')
```

Answer (score 0):

CSVs are nothing but comma separated strings for each column and new-line separated for each row, which you can do like so:

```
data = [[1, 2, 4], ['A', 'AB', 2], ['P', 23, 4]]

data_string = '\n'.join([', '.join(map(str, row)) for row in data])
with open('data.csv', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(data_string.encode())
```